# Regex in javascript with latin and turkish characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, turkish

I am trying to replace all the non latin/turkish characters, but something is wrong and I can't find it.

For example:

```
var texto = '*istediğiniz*';
if (texto.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ\- ]/g)){

    //only letters, numbers and turkish letters are allowed
    texto = texto.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ\- ]/g, ''); 
}

console.log(texto);
```

As a result, my word is output incorrectly: `istediiniz`. The output should be `istediğiniz`.

Comment: why are you even putting this in an `if`?

Comment: ^ Right...`replace` won't replace if there's nothing to replace...

Comment: i get your desired output

Comment: Oh my God, this is getting existential. Should I remove the `if`?

Comment: yes, and also ensure proper encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10924295/1291428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encode your javascript file into `utf-8` and update your meta tag to:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Hold me a sec. I will test

Comment: Better use short description from html5 `<meta charset="utf-8">` This work even for IE6