# Problems with website collation

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8, collation

I'm making a website where information is stored in the Lithuanian language.
It basically consists of all latin letters and some unique letters:
Ąą, Čč, Ęę, Ėė, Įį, Šš, Ųų, Ūū, Žž.

I'm trying to set my database collation to utf8_general_ci or cp1257_lithuanian_ci.
I prefer using utf8_general_ci, though.

Either of theese collations work fine when printing Lithuanian characters on page,
but the php code doesn't seem to understand the Lithuanian characters. For example - 
when I try to swap all Lithuanian characters to simillar latin letters (Ą = A, Ė = E) php
can't match these letters with Lithuanian letters described in the code. When I try to lower-case Lithuanian text, Lithuanian letters turn into 2 latin letters.

What should I try changing to make it work?

EDIT:

The code:

```
<?php
    echo 'ĄąČčĘęĖėĮįŠšŲųŪūŽž';
?>
```

returns:

Ä„Ä…ÄÄ¨ÄÄ™Ä–Ä—Ä®ÄÆÅ ÅÅ²Å³ÅŖÅ«Å½Å¾

What I have already done:

```
-All files set to "UTF8 No Mark"
-Html has a propper meta tag
-Mysql database collation is "utf8_general_ci"
```

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924207/json-encode-wont-encode-french-characters/10924295#10924295

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your files are UTF-8 without BOM encoded.

And your php page should sent an UTF-8 header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget one thing. You have to inform browser about encoding like this:

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

or this:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

or this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

If you don't inform your browser about encoding - browser will use default encoding from its configuration, or it will try to autodetect.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you must be aware of is PHP doesn't define an  internal encoding for strings: strings are simply array of bytes, so to represent text in PHP you alway need two things:

1. an array of bytes
2. the encoding scheme

The byte content of the string literals that appear in your code depends on how you generate the file (in concrete terms, it depends on the encoding used by your text editors). The PHP interpreter doesn't bother about the encoding of the scripts, as long as it is ASCII-compatible, so the parser can correctly read it and recognize the syntax.

Eventually, to get literal strings output as intended, you need to communicate the encoding used by the text file to the browser. This is done at the transport level, with the HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=<INSERT YOUR SOURCES ENCODING>
```

In PHP headers must be sent before any output with the funcion `header()`